# Micronaut Swagger..Unable to render this definition

Tags: maven, swagger, micronaut

> Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not
> specify a valid version field.
>
> Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported
> version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n
> (for example, openapi: 3.0.0)

I have found similar posts but they are based on spring boot

eg. [Swagger..Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not specify a valid version field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951641/swagger-unable-to-render-this-definition-the-provided-definition-does-not-speci)

My SwaggerConfiguration is based on the repo from:
https://github.com/frehov/micronaut-swagger-server

Does it has to do with some pom dependency/version?

Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

AnnotationProcessorPaths

```
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
                        <artifactId>micronaut-openapi</artifactId>
                        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
```

Comment: Hello, your imports seems to be correct. I'm not used to maven annotations since I use micronaut only with gradle, but you are unsing swagger 3 and you have micronaut-openapi plugin and micronaut version is the same as micronaut-openapi version.
Can you link the application class and some swagger documentation ?

Comment: I think another problem, I will post another question

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331458/micronaut-swagger-configuration-url-with-null-values