# Getting 404 eror with Swager UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

I have non boot spring mvc application. When I hit the swagger-ui.html or swagger-ui/. I am getting the 404 error.

My config classes:

SpringFoxConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {}
```

SpringConfig

```
@ComponentScan("com.leverx.internship_project")
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:src/main/resources");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:src/main/resources");
  }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: can you try as dependency just `<dependency><groupId>io.springfox</groupId> <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId><version>3.0.0</version></dependency>`  instead of the two you provided? also, you either need to access it via /swagger-ui/ or /swagger-ui/index.html. the swagger-ui.html is no longer available, afaik

Comment: also, I don't think you need `@EnableSwagger2` nor to define the  `addResourceHandlers`. just create a bean of type `Docket`, like ```@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }```

Comment: @AndreiSfat Doesn't work...

Comment: are you using by any chance server.servlet.context-path in your configuration? what are using? spring boot?

Comment: @AndreiSfat I don't use spring boot and also i don't use any configurations, except for the ones I posted

Comment: Consider moving to `springdoc`. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178343/springfox-3-0-0-is-not-working-with-spring-boot-2-6-0/70178391#70178391 you can read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

step1: try my config file for you, just copy and past
step2: enjoy

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
}

private ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("phat").description("Test Management REST API")
            .contact(new Contact("tester", "https://test.vn/", "tester_pro@gmail.com")).license("Apache 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html").version("1.0.0").build();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
}
```

Comment: @caothanphatit Doesn't work, and I noticed that .html doesn't compile in target/META-INF