# getting error when adding springboot actuator 2.6.6 and swagger 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, spring-boot-actuator, swagger-3.0

I am facing an error with my spring-boot application after adding the spring-boot actuator.
error saying

```
failed to start bean documentationPlugginBootstraper, nested exception NullPointer
```

attached is an image of an error

[image]

I am using Gradle as a build tool and below is my gradle.build file image

[image]

I need to use spring-boot version 2.6.6 and I added the below line to application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

The application is working fine and loading swagger API documentation when I comment spring-boot actuator dependent but I also need that to check the health

Is there any recommendation for fixing this issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

for resolving this I changed my swagger config class according to the below link answer
[Springfox 3.0.0 is not working with Spring Boot 2.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178343/springfox-3-0-0-is-not-working-with-spring-boot-2-6-0)